# multiple if statements used to update database entries

Tags: php, mysql, if-statement

Have the following code that on button click goes to database named 'colleges' where columns are named 'college1', 'college2', etc (to 'college10') as well as 'sports1', 'sports2', etc (to 'sports10')

```
if ($row['college4'] == null) {
     $sql = "UPDATE colleges SET college3 = NULL, sports3 = NULL";
}
if ($row['college3'] == null) {
     $sql = "UPDATE colleges SET college2 = NULL, sports2 = NULL";
}
if ($row['college2'] == null) {
     $sql = "UPDATE colleges SET college1 = NULL, sports1 = NULL";
}
```

Essentially, if a specific column in the database equals NULL, then set the preceding column to NULL. The prior coding works, however, only for the most recent if statement (In this case, college2). Once that executes, the remaining if statements are ignored (i.e. college 4 and college 3.

If more explanation is needed please let me know. I think I am just looking for a how to on having the sql queries recognize in a cascading manner. Thanks.

Full PHP:

```
<?php
            session_start();

            define("DB_HOST", "");
            define("DB_USER", "");
            define("DB_PASS", "");
            define("DB_NAME", "");

            // Create connection
            $conn = new mysqli(DB_HOST, DB_USER, DB_PASS, DB_NAME);

            if ($conn->connect_error) {
                die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
            }

                    if ($row['college4'] == null) {
                        $sql = "UPDATE colleges SET college3 = NULL, sports3 = NULL";
                    }
                    if ($row['college3'] == null) {
                        $sql = "UPDATE colleges SET college2 = NULL, sports2 = NULL";
                    }
                    if ($row['college2'] == null) {
                        $sql = "UPDATE colleges SET college1 = NULL, sports1 = NULL";
                    }

            if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
                echo "Record deleted successfully";
            } else {
                echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
            }

            mysqli_close($conn);
        ?>
```

Comment: Correct me if I am totally wrong, but it sound like you just need something like `elseif`.

Comment: tried that too...more of the same. Ill mess with that again though

Comment: If you post the code in the question and tell exactly where the cascading logic goes wrong, maybe with two or three examples, it would be easier to help.

Comment: updated at top. furthermore, with elseif statements, it updates 'college4' but does not execute the other 2 statements when applicable.

Comment: Have you ever thought about normalizing your database? This would avoid the problem you are having right now. I mean, columns, from `college1` to `college10` ...? I would consider putting that into a separate table. But sure, that is not the question here ...

Comment: Just to understand it - "if a specific column in the database equals NULL, then set the preceding column to NULL" means that you expect all preceding colums to be set to NULL?

Comment: You're updating your entire db because of missing `WHERE` clauses, unless that's what you want. I also can't see exactly where you executing those queries. @MichaelPhilibin

Comment: not ALL preceding columns to NULL, just the column directly before it. For example, if college4 = NULL, then just college3 and sports 3 should be set to NULL

Comment: @Fred-ii- I didn't think the WHERE was necessary if I was setting specific columns to NULL.

Comment: @MichaelPhilibin the `WHERE` clause is necessary to update a specific row. As I said earlier, you're updating your entire table without them.

Comment: @Fred-ii- Even though my SET is calling out specific columns in database? So would this be correct... elseif ($row['college4'] == null) {
                        $sql = "UPDATE colleges SET college3 = NULL, sports3 = NULL WHERE college3 != NULL, sports3 != NULL";
                    }

Comment: @MichaelPhilibin *Even* with `SET`. See the manuals https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html  --- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimization.html

Comment: @MichaelPhilibin ok wait; you just edited your comment above and that wasn't in  your question and the `WHERE` need `AND` or `OR`, not commas that's why it failed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All of  your UPDATES are missing a `WHERE` clause and using `AND` or `OR` as separators, not commas for what you [posted in comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44217038/multiple-if-statements-used-to-update-database-entries/44217358#comment75445297_44217038):

```
UPDATE colleges SET college3 = NULL, sports3 = NULL 
WHERE college3 != NULL, sports3 != NULL
```

should read as:

```
UPDATE colleges SET college3 = NULL, sports3 = NULL 
WHERE college3 != NULL AND sports3 != NULL
```

or using the `OR` logical operator, depending on what the criteria is.

Plus, as I mentioned in comments; you are updating your entire database without a `WHERE` clause.

Consult the manuals:

- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/update.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/where-optimization.html

Comment: the mentioned is not updating the database. but does return my echo that it should have been updated.

Comment: @MichaelPhilibin I don't know which API is used to connect/query with, so I am unable to help to give you the proper functions for error checking and to see if the queries were successful. Are you using `mysql_`, `mysqli_`, PDO, other? Or where you are executing the queries.

Comment: @MichaelPhilibin if you're going to update your question with the code I gave, people might ask themselves *"He has the `WHERE` clause, so why the answer?"* and I may get downvoted for it. To which seeing it now, is exactly what you went and did.

Comment: @MichaelPhilibin seeing you're using `mysqli_` instead of `if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE)` to check to see if it truly was successful, use `mysqli_affected_rows()` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.affected-rows.php - also, all conditions must be met so the `AND`'s may need to be `OR`'s - if one of those fail, they all fail. You also have `if ($row['college4'] == null) {` and that should come from a `SELECT` somewhere inside a `while` loop. If what you posted inside your full code, then you will need to update it again. If it is your full code, then it failed.

Comment: Ok great. Thanks for taking the time Fred! The while loop makes sense. As for the AND and OR's, there should never be a time where it should be OR with my form.

Comment: @MichaelPhilibin I noticed your new question https://stackoverflow.com/q/44245846/1415724 - I take it that you solved the question you posted here?

Comment: Oops! forgot to approve this! @Fred New question was essentially a typo. Can delete if necessary.

Comment: No worries @MichaelPhilibin I was just curious :-) *Cheers*

Answer (score 0):

```
$max = 4; // set maximum number of College 

$sql = '';
for($i=$max; $i>=2; $i--) {
    if($row['college'.$i] == null) {
        $sql .= "UPDATE colleges SET college".($i-1)." = NULL, sports".($i-1)." = NULL;";
    }
}
```

In this case, you have to run query after for loop. You can run inside if statement too. Then code will be:

```
$max = 4; // set maximum number of College

for($i=$max; $i>=2; $i--) {
    if($row['college'.$i] == null) {
        $sql = "UPDATE colleges SET college".($i-1)." = NULL, sports".($i-1)." = NULL";
// Query Run Code Here
    }
}
```